# Move window to the other worksapce not working after Upate

Tags: 16.04, gnome, shortcut-keys

Yesterday, after updating my Ubuntu GNOME 16.04, Shortcuts for moving windows not working.

When I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>up</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>down</kbd> the focused window does not move to the other worksapce. I reassigned shortcut form keyboard settings. and I noticed that I can not assign those keys anymore. I can assign something else for example <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>up</kbd> but <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> can not be in a shortcut anymore.

Why this problem is happening? Is it something new with GNOME? or something went wrong after the update? How can I fix it?

my GNOME Shell version is 3.18.5.

Comment: They probably have been reset to default, try Ctrl+Alt+Left or Right.  Ctrl+ F1, F2 ... should work too!
You can set them in Windows Manager under the Keyboard tab - down the list!!

Comment: @KenMollerup It didn't reset to the default, because when i went to the keyboard shortcut settings, the shortcut was the as same before. I just dont know why I canot use ctrl+alt+shift+something in a shortcut after the update.